# Django-Oscar Basket customization

Tags: django-forms, django-oscar, django-formwizard

I am using Djnago-oscar for Solar energy equipment based eCommerce site. I need to add an option to "Basket" model with "Battery Name", "Notes" and 
"Manufacturer". There is a reason I don't want to add it in subclass AbstractProduct. Rather I want to built it with subclass Basket model.
Now I need help to understand my workflow to make this work with AddToBasket form. In Django-oscar/basket there are formsets.py using formset factory and a form. 
I am a bit confused and decided to get help from community.

Following is the code:

**models.py**

```
MANUFACTURERS = (
    ('UPS SYSTEMS', 'UPS SYSTEMS'),
    ('VOLTA', 'VOLTA'),
    ('TOSHIBA ', 'TOSHIBA '),
)

BATTERIES = (
    ('LITHIUM', 'LITHIUM'),
    ('NICAD', 'NICAD'),
    ('NIFE ', 'NIFE '),
)

class AddBattery(AbstractBasket):
    battery_name = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=BATTERIES)
    manufacturers = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=MANUFACTURERS)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=6)
    notes = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.battery_name


class Basket(AbstractBasket):
    add_bat=models.ForeignKey(_(u'Add a Batter'), to=AddBattery, null=True, blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models import Sum
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from oscar.forms import widgets
from oscar.apps.basket.forms import BasketLineForm as CoreBasketLineForm,\
SavedLineForm as CoreSavedLineForm, BasketVoucherForm as CoreBasketVoucherForm,\
AddToBasketForm as CoreAddToBasketForm

from .models import AddBattery
from oscar.core.loading import get_model, get_classes

Line = get_model('basket', 'line')
Basket = get_model('basket', 'basket')
Product = get_model('catalogue', 'product')



class BasketLineForm(CoreBasketLineForm):
    class AddBatteryForm(CoreBasketLineForm.Meta):
        model = AddBattery
        fields = ['battery_name', 'manufacturers', 'comment']
```

**views.py**

I need help to figure this part because it has so much nested elements and I couldn't get it right.
Help is much appreciated.

**Templates:**
I can work this out because I need admin to have ability to add it but end user only will have an option to select from with price.
Upon selection by client I need to have consolidated price with products and plus the battery. Any advise for this part would be great as well
about how to get consolidated price from both in cart for checkout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't add your fields in Basket model. You need to subclass Line model instead.
2. Subclass forms.py and formsets.py. You only need to change BasketLineForm, SavedLineForm and AddBasketForm. After you subclass these in your own forms. Leave rest of the Forms.
3. Subclass BaseBasketLineFormSet and BaseSavedLineFormSet in your own formsets edit as per your need.
4. Subclass BasketView and AddBasketView by supplying the forms, formsets and args/kwargs you added.
5. Copy template directory from app to your own folder and add form at basket_total.html as you mentioned above as the last part.

But having said that...its against the workflow as explained by others. There is no limitation at all for you in any case as far as programming is concerned. But you should always consider the most reasonable path to solve your problems.

Comment: Why not to add it in Basket? Is there some sense to it?

Comment: Basket is locked with Line added to it. Line includes all the product related attributes/features etc. Adding new fields to basket means you will have to redo the whole structure of Basket. Rest is up to you to decide. This is closest to what you want. Instead use solution by built-in Oscar's features.

Comment: Makes sense. I will definitely try this and will update you if I got questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question with several different components. I can offer the following suggestions for you to look into:

1. Doing this in the basket model is almost certainly not going to serve you well, because  you will not be able to pass this custom information to the order object when it is created. More importantly, what you're trying to do doesn't seem to be a basket issue, just a product/variant issue (see below).
2. There are two possibilities I can see from what you have described:

   a. A battery is a separate product that the user buys along with the main product. It has its own pricing and availability.

   b. A battery isn't a separate product, it's just one of a fixed set of choices that a customer has when buying the main product.

If (a), then you just need to have separate products, and some logic that allows a user to select the accessory product (battery) at the same time as the main one, and that adds both to the basket simultaneously.

If (b), then these are essentially [variants](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/topics/modelling_your_catalogue.html#variants-parent-and-child-products) where one product has multiple variations with different pricing. In this case you should use Oscar's built-in support for variants.

In any case, modifying the basket model will cause you a lot of problems IMO.

Comment: Can you please still update the answer with Workflow that at least should explain the map of inherited view. I will deal with problems if there are any. I would be really thankful to you.

Comment: Not really, because you first need to decide which approach makes most sense for you - I described two possible ones above. If you use variants then there is very little to do because these are support out of the box.

Comment: I want to go with option 1 certainly because I guess with this I will really be able to solve a lot of Django-Oscar issues I have with no more help.

Comment: @ShaziaNusrat Going with a variant would be much simpler like solarissmoke pointed out. Oscar has built-in support for that, otherwise (option 1) there will be a lot of workarounds which may cause other bugs / headaches down the line.