# How to set product attributes to basket line in Oscar

Tags: django, django-oscar

I'm new to `Django-oscar` and working on `Basket` now
I can add products as lines to the basket easily but what if I want to choose a specific Product attribute to add to basket for example
product A has attributes `{'size': ['M', 'S'], 'color': ['red', 'blue']}`
what should i do if i want to add product A with size M and color blue to the basket?

Comment: Related - [Django-Oscar Basket customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557546/django-oscar-basket-customization)

Comment: @shad0w_wa1k3r thanks for reply, and it's useful in other ways but it didn't help me in this issue

Answer (score 4):

for those who will come looking for the same issue,
i found a way to do this:
There is an Oscar Model called `Option` you can add the attributes you generally add to your items `eg. Size Color Flavor ..etc` and pass the value from product's attributes
because

```
basket.add_product()
```

has `options` argument and only accept Option instance so we need to have it
it's passed as list of objects in this way:

```
[
{'option': Option.objects.get(name="name"), 'value': 'Value'},
]
```

please if you know a better way to do it, comment here :)

Comment: how did you get your Option assigned to a product. in the database (otherwise, the form will not validate)? I was not able doing this with the dashboard...

Comment: @benzkji mainly the Option is attached to Basket Line (Option as a foreign key - Value as text or whatever, see AbstractLineAttribute class and the Line object has a Product object related or attached to it

Comment: @AshrafEmad Could you please elaborate it a little more? can i see the code?
you are talking here about the product option or the multi option group ?